# Term for people who are somewhere between blue collar workers and white collar workers

Tags: single-word-requests

Blue Collar iplies production or assembly line.  White collar implies professional.  I'm looking for a term that would describe people who work for the railroad, or are police officers, or fire fighters, or

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Please spend some time completing your question, as it is currently seems incomplete. Finish the last sentence, provide a sample sentence to illustrate how you intend to use the word if you had it, and what options you have considered and rejected.

Comment: Your definition of *blue collar* is too restrictive. In the U.S., railroad workers, police officers, and firefighters would all be considered blue-collar workers in that their occupations historically require less formal education than a bachelor's degree to enter (as well as having a physical component, at least historically, and hourly as opposed to annual compensation). Nuclear power reactor operators are also classified as blue collar workers, as are air traffic controllers, food and health inspectors, utility piping designers, and avionics technicians among others.

Comment: @choster Are you saying that bank tellers, accounts clerks and insurance salespeople are considered blue collar workers in  the US? All of those jobs and many others which have not required degree level qualifications but do not require much in the way of physical labour are considered 'white collar' jobs in the UK. Air traffic controller would be thought of as a white collar job here as well.

Comment: @boldben It is more compared than that, because in the era these terms were coined, jobs were heavily gendered and racialized. A bank teller was probably also a woman and the job not respected as "real" work to begin with, thus the abortive attempts to popularize the term "pink collar" for medium-skilled office and education work. An air traffic controller is definitely blue collar work here. It is hourly shift work in a unionized industrial setting with no advanced formal education required.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. I couldn't think of anything off the top of my head so I did a quick search and found [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Designation_of_workers_by_collar_color). The new types of 'collars' certainly seems to be a response to the changing labor landscape and increase in the need for and prevalence of technical skills.

To your point, railroad engineers or technicians would be likely be 'grey collar'. I would classify the FD/PD as blue collar though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey-collar

Comment: Grey-collar apparently has no fixed meaning. Also, most clergy have advanced degrees, so unless moving a lot of folding chairs turns one's collar to grey, this is an odd classification.

Comment: I think we're outside the realm of fixed meanings, even with blue and white. The only difference between a shift foreman and the President of the United States is one of scale, and yet the one wears a blue collar and the other wears a white one.